# Find the path used by the command line when calling an executable

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command-prompt, windows-shell

**I am experiencing the following problem:**

I would like to run `ecd.exe` from a command-line.

I have added its full path to the 'path' environment-variable.

When calling `ecd.exe` from command-line, I get the following output:

```
Error: ecd.exe should be located under the Eclipse home directory.
```

This executable runs correctly when I add its full path in the command-line.

---

I've figured that an identical file exists in some other `path` folder.

But I have not been able to find it anywhere within the file-system.

How can I find the path used by the command line when calling this executable?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for the edit (wasn't really sure how to refer to "CMD"). Any chance you know how to resolve this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Under `C:\Freescale\CW MCU v10.6\eclipse`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I thought that the shell was executing a file of identical name from a different path. I wanted to know which path that might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "pathd=%cd%;%path%"
SET "pathd=%pathd:)=^)%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('echo %pathd:;=^&ECHO %') DO IF EXIST "%%~a\j*.exe" ECHO %%~a

GOTO :EOF
```

This should find - well, `J*.exe` files on the path (since I don't have `ecd.exe`) - just substitute `ecd.exe` for `j*.exe`.

It appends the current path to the current directoryname separated by `;` then changes each `)` to `^)` in the resulting string.

The `for` operates on the concatenated enhanced path-string by substituting for `;` with `&echo` - the carets before the `)` on the previous line and the `&` in this line "escapes" the character, cause `cmd` to disregard the special meaning and treat it as an ordinary character.

This provides `%%a` as each individual `path` directory in turn; see whether the file (`j*.exe`) exists in the directory, and `echo` the directoryname if the file is found.

Comment: Yes - that would be an idea.

Comment: Thanks, it's working!!! But unfortunately working, because it leads me to a dead end on my original purpose (which is to understand why it behaves in a different manner when I call it with / without the full path). Perhaps I should post a different question, I'll accept your answer in any case. Thanks again :)